# @react-google-maps/api is not showing marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I tried console log but it won't show what postition is used by marker.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, Marker, LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const center = {
  lat: 19.1383,
  lng: 77.321,
};

const style = {
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100%",
};
const Map = () => {
  const onLoad = (marker) => {
    console.log("marker: ", marker);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={style} zoom={15} center={center}>
          <Marker position={center}  />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

I tried getting user's currrent location using HTML's geolocation API but it won't work.

Comment: *It won't show* / *It won't work* are not proper problem descriptions. Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue along with debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include `onLoad` props on your `<Marker />` component and use your `onLoad` **function** as the value inside the prop to call it whenever it loads. I'm assuming here that your marker will show on the `center` that you specified. So it should look like this:

```
<Marker onLoad={onLoad} position={center}  />
```

I tried running your code on codesandbox after making the changes and it worked just fine. Your whole `Map` component should look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, Marker, LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const center = {
  lat: 19.1383,
  lng: 77.321
};

const style = {
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100%"
};
const Map = () => {
  const onLoad = (marker) => {
    console.log("marker: ", marker);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={style} zoom={15} center={center}>
          <Marker onLoad={onLoad} position={center} />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Proof of concept sandbox here if you want to check: https://codesandbox.io/s/proof-of-concept-sandbox-on-showing-markers-stzg9g?file=/src/Map.js

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey, @Yrll can you show me how to filter out the mosques only from this package?

Comment: Well you did not mention that on your question. This answer is to only help you with showing the marker in relation to the code that you provided. As what MrUpsidown said on his comment on your post, please do provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is clear enough that won't cause people helping you to put in the double effort. If you want, you can accept this one if this fixes the marker issue and ask another question for another specific problem.